# Angularjs: Adding custom properties or fields or calculations to a Json object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am new to angularjs. I have a Rest service which sends the below data of `saleItems` on get request.

```
saleItems = [
  {
    "id": 236,
    "variant": "Oval Holder",
    "mrp": "66.00"
  },
  {
    "id": 237,
    "variant": "Angle Holder",
    "mrp": "52.00"
  }
]
```

And my template looks like:

```
<table>
  <tr><th>Sale Invoice</th></tr>
  <tr>
    <th>No.</th>
    <th>Item.</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Rate</th>
    <th>Discount</th>
    <th>Discount Amount</th>
    <th>Total Amount</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.saleItems | filter:$ctrl.query | orderBy:$ctrl.orderProp">
    <td>{{$index + 1}}</a></td>
    <td>{{item.variant}}</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="{{item.sale_quantity}}"></td>
    <td class='amt'>{{item.mrp | currency : "₹" : 2}}</td>
    <td class='amt'><input type="text" placeholder="0.00" value="{{item.discount_percent}}"></td>
    <td class='amt' >{{item.total_amount | currency : "₹" : 2}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>{{sale_total_amount}}</td></tr>
</table>
```

As you can see from the above template, I would like to have an input for `item.sale_quantity`, `item.discount_percent` and a `readonly` field `item.total_amount`.

Whenever the `item.sale_quantity` is updated, then the `item.total_amount` field should also be updated, along with `sale_total_amount`(sum of all item.total_amount's for each row).

Moreover I would like to do some validation in the controller against `item.sale_quantity`.

Just looking for some insights. Noob here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-change`. `ng-change ="expression"` evaluates the expression whenever there is change in value of data where `ng-change` is used.

So first initialise the **item.total_amount** and **item.sale_quantity** by adding 
`ng-init="item.total_amount=0;item.sale_quantity =0"` in first `<td>` tag
and then replace

`<td><input type="text" value="{{item.sale_quantity}}"></td>`  **with**

```
<td><input type="text" value="{{item.sale_quantity}}" ng-chnage="item.total_amount = item.sale_quantity * item.mrp"></td>
```

.

So now whenever there is change in `item.sale_quantity` expression `item.total_amount = item.sale_quantity * item.mrp` will be evaluated and newly calculated value will be assigned in **item.total_amount**.

Comment: There is no method in the controller to calculate the `item.total_amount = item.sale_quantity * item.mrp`. I would like to have `total_amount` as property of `item` as well as `sale_quantity`. How to achieve that?

Comment: @Shameless `total_amount` and `sale_quantity` are property of item object already right? cos you are accessing then as ` item. total_amount`  and ` item. sale_quantity`

Comment: No. they aren't. I want them to be so. Take a look at `saleItems`

Comment: @Shameless one way is after you get the response from rest service iterate in saleItems and assign property total_amount and sale_quantity to each object. another is you can change `ng-change="m1()"` in my answer to `ng-chnage="item.total_amount = item.sale_quantity * item.mrp"` and before that in first `<td>` tag `add ng-init="item.total_amount=0;item.sale_quantity =0"`

Comment: That did work. Please update your answer with the above comment alongside some explanation. Thanks.